# Escribir al seleccionar un texto en TextBox

Tags: c#, windows-forms, visual-studio-2017

Trabajo con Windows Forms, C# 
Tengo la necesidad de seleccionar el texto que esta en un TextBox y cuando ingreso un número o letra se borre lo que esta seleccionado y reciba lo que estoy ingresando.

El código que ocupe es el siguiente:

```
if (e.KeyData == (Keys.R | Keys.Alt))
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtDineroRecibido.Text))
            {
                txtDineroRecibido.Focus();
                txtDineroRecibido.SelectionStart = 0;
                txtDineroRecibido.SelectionLength = txtDineroRecibido.Text.Length;
                e.Handled = true;
            }
        }
```

Este código esta en el evento KeyDow del formulario, el problema que tengo es que cuando selecciono el texto e ingreso un dígito no se borra lo seleccionado ni ingresa nada, tengo que borrar lo seleccionado con la tecla retroceso y ahí recién puedo ingresar datos.

El TextBox es control personalizado que se comporta de la siguiente manera cuando ingreso números decimales es lo que estoy usando.

```
case TipoDato.Numeric:
                //verificar si el textbox contiene el caracter punto y actualizar nuestra variable a true si ya se tiene un punto
                if (this.Text.Contains(".") == true)
                    punto = true;
                else
                    punto = false;

                //permitir solo los caracteres de digitos y punto
                // e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Home
                if (char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) || e.KeyChar == '.')
                {
                    //validar si el usuario esta ingresando el caracter (punto)
                    if (e.KeyChar == '.')
                    {
                        //limitar el numero de puntos en el textbox
                        if (punto)
                        {
                            e.Handled = true;// si ya existe un punto, bloquear el caracter
                            return;
                        }
                        //si no existe ningun punto en el textbox, permitir el caracter
                        punto = true;

                    }

                    //si el caracter es un digito
                    //comprobar que el cuadro de texto cumpla con la expresion regular:
                    //0 a n digitos(punto)n numero de decimales
                    //si cumple con la expresion, permitir el digito ingresado
                    if (Regex.IsMatch(this.Text, @"^\d*\.\d{" + decimales + "}$")) e.Handled = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    //si es tecla de control especial, permitirla
                    if (!Char.IsControl(e.KeyChar))
                    {
                        e.Handled = true;
                        return;
                    }
                }
                break;
```

¿Como puedo solucionarlo?

Saludos!

Comment: O sea, recapitulemos, el problema es cuando lo selecciona este trozo de codigo?

Comment: Así es el problema es cuando selecciono el código por la combinación de teclas, pensé que se iba a comportar como se hace manual pero no.

Comment: Usas mucho `e.Handled = true` ¿la segunda parte del código, el `switch`, también ocurre en el `KeyDown`?, estaría bien saber qué flujo estás siguiendo en los gestores de eventos.

Comment: ¿En qué evento se ingresa a la validación de tu TextBox personalizado? ¿Cuánto vale decimales?

Comment: @CarlosPozos si te refieres al evento del control personalizado es en `OnKeyPress` si te refieres donde lo implemento solo dentro si se cumplen las combinaciones de teclas en el cual solo selecciono el texto que ya esta ahí.